# Issue with laravel dompdf when convert view to pdf, the content will be enlarged

Tags: css, laravel, dompdf

I am converting view to pdf, it looks good when view in browser when generate view to pdf using dompdf, then the format all not nice.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.print');
$pdf->output();
```

Using dompdf

[image]

using google chrome

[image]
Can i know any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with your css. Setting max-heights should solve the issue. Can you please provide the code for the view and your stylesheet?

Also, have you tried the viewport tag in your header?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yes, i included this meta. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the reason for this is that `dompdf` cannot open external CSS files.

So the fix is easy, replace any `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >` copying the content directly in the html style tag.

In your case take the content of `bootstrap.min.css` and place it in the header:

```
<head>
    <style>
        /*....ALL EXTERNAL CSS GOES HERE.....*/
    </style>
</head>
```